# LINQ join with multiple conditions?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following working SQL query:

```
select a.Id, a.Name
from Addresses a join Companies c 
                on c.AddressId = a.Id
                or c.MailAddressId = a.Id
                or c.Id = a.CompanyId
where c.Id = *CompanyId* and a.Name = *AddressName*
```

that checks if an Address with the provided Address name is linked to a company with the provided Company id.

How can I express this in LINQ for EF?

**Update**: The Address and Company classes are as follows (only details relevant to this question are included):

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int? CompanyId {get; set;}
    public virtual Company {get; set;}
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int AddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual Address Address {get; set;}

    public int? MailAddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual Address MailAddress {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Address> DeliveryAddresses {get; set;}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ supports only equal joins. in other cases you should use cross-join and where:

```
from a in Addresses
from c in Companies
where (c.AddressId == a.Id || c.MailAddressId == a.Id || c.Id == a.CompanyId)
         &&  (c.Id == *CompanyId* && a.Name == *AddressName*)
select new{a.Id, a.Name}
```

Comment: or it is possible to use custom `Comparer` in `Join`.

Comment: yes, that should work too, but will not be possible to use queries than, have to use extension methods

Comment: This one throws an exception: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.Company'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: The problem definitely comes from, because you use Models.Company as parameter, you should assign to temporary variable before using it in linq query. something ilke c.Id = tmpCompany, instead of c.Id = Model.Company

Comment: Not quite. I'm using only int and string as params:               int CompanyId = 62;
string AddressName = "Delivery Address 1";

var q = (from a in Addresses
    from c in Companies
    where (c.AddressId == a.Id || c.MailAddressId == a.Id || c.Id == a.CompanyId)
    && c.Id == CompanyId
    && a.Name == AddressName
    select new {a.Id, a.Name})
    .ToList();
  
q.Dump();

Comment: @bdaniel7, I don't see any Model.Company in the code you provide, I think the issue is in anotyer place